# Convert datetime and objects to string (doctrine, symfony)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, data-conversion

I want to write changes into DB, but I always receive an error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted
>   to string

I receive changes in entity using `getEntityChangeSet()` and then I want to parse data into readable format and then write it into db:

```
$changes = $uow->getEntityChangeSet($entity);
        $log='';
        foreach ($changes as $key=>$change)
        {
            $log.= "{$key} => Old Value:{$change[0]} => New Value:{$change[1]}";
        }
```

If I do not try to write readable data doctrine whites something like this to `change_set` field:

> a:3:{s:5:"value";a:2:{i:0;N;i:1;s:3:"120";}s:4:"item";a:2:{i:0;N;i:1;O:21:"AppBundle\Entity\Item":6:{s:25:"AppBundle\Entity\Itemid";i:127;s:27:"AppBundle\Entity\Itemname";s:7:"newitem";s:13:"*categories";O:33:"Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection":2:{s:13:"*collection";O:43:"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection":1:{s:53:"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollectionelements";a:2:{i:0;O:25:"AppBundle\Entity\Category":7:{s:29:"AppBundle\Entity\Categoryid";i:2;s:31:"AppBundle\Entity\Categoryname";s:10:"child
>   to
>   1";s:33:"AppBundle\Entity\Categoryparent";O:40:"Proxies__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Category":8:{s:17:"**isInitialized**";b:0;s:29:"AppBundle\Entity\Categoryid";i:1;s:31:"AppBundle\Entity\Categoryname";N;s:33:"AppBundle\Entity\Categoryparent";N;s:35:"AppBundle\Entity\Categorychildren";N;s:8:"*items";N;s:36:"AppBundle\Entity\CategorycreatedAt";N;s:36:"AppBundle\Entity\CategoryupdatedAt";N;}s:35:"AppBundle\Entity\Categorychildren";O:33:"Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection":2:{s:13:"*collection";O:43:"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection":1:{s:53:"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollectionelements";a:0:{}}s:14:"*initialized";b:0;}s:8:"*items";O:33:"Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection":2:{s:13:"*collection";O:43:"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection":1:{s:53:"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollectionelements";a:0:{}}s:14:"*initialized";b:0;}s:36:"AppBundle\Entity\CategorycreatedAt";N;s:36:"AppBundle\Entity\CategoryupdatedAt";N;}i:1;O:25:"AppBundle\Entity\Category":7:{s:29:"AppBundle\Entity\Categoryid";i:4;s:31:"AppBundle\Entity\Categoryname";s:8:"child1.1";s:33:"AppBundle\Entity\Categoryparent";r:13;s:35:"AppBundle\Entity\Categorychildren";O:33:"Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection":2:{s:13:"*collection";O:43:"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection":1:{s:53:"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollectionelements";a:0:{}}s:14:"*initialized";b:0;}s:8:"*items";O:33:"Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection":2:{s:13:"*collection";O:43:"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection":1:{s:53:"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollectionelements";a:0:{}}s:14:"*initialized";b:0;}s:36:"AppBundle\Entity\CategorycreatedAt";N;s:36:"AppBundle\Entity\CategoryupdatedAt";N;}}}s:14:"*initialized";b:1;}s:13:"*attributes";N;s:32:"AppBundle\Entity\ItemcreatedAt";O:8:"DateTime":3:{s:4:"date";s:26:"2018-03-19
>   10:22:47.000000";s:13:"timezone_type";i:3;s:8:"timezone";s:3:"UTC";}s:32:"AppBundle\Entity\ItemupdatedAt";N;}}s:9:"attribute";a:2:{i:0;N;i:1;O:26:"AppBundle\Entity\Attribute":3:{s:30:"AppBundle\Entity\Attributeid";i:96;s:33:"AppBundle\Entity\Attributealias";s:5:"price";s:32:"AppBundle\Entity\Attributename";s:5:"price";}}}

Any idea how to convert date and another objects into string? Or I need to use another method for solving this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check if the value is a \DateTime object, then convert it.

```
...
if ($change[0] instanceof \DateTime) {
    $stringValue = $value->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
// Do the same for $change[1]
...
```

Comment: I try to do something like this: `foreach ($changes as $key=>$change)
        {
            if ($change[0] instanceof \DateTime) {
                $this->str = $change[0]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            }

            if ($change[1] instanceof \DateTime) {
                $this->str1 = $change[1]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                $log.= "{$separator}{$key}: Old Value: {$this->str} => New Value: {$this->str1}";
            } else
                $log.= "{$separator}{$key}: Old Value: {$change[0]} => New Value: {$change[1]}";

            $separator=', ';
        }`

Comment: and for updated entity it works fine, because only name (string) and date (converted yet) are usable. But if I want to POST something new, there are at least 3 Entities (related)... and if I try to write them, i receive an error that this value can not be converted to string, because it belongs to one of 3 Entities...